# How to wavy underlines Textbox in dot Net

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi

I need wavy underline in textbox (NOT RichTextBox). after googling i see some projects, they have done this (eg: sharpspell) I know this should not be easy but I need find a solution.

thanks.

Comment: I think you have to either use a third-party control, or do the painting of the control yourself.

Comment: What's wrong with `RichTextBox`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294593/cannot-type-unicode-in-richtextbox-properly

Comment: @PatrickHofman how to painting of the control myself, pls give me some source code.

Comment: @user3545835: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414693/textbox-custom-onpaint