# OnPaint event not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am overriding the paint event as I need to give a text box an extra property. In this case the extra property is a border colour for a text box. When the User Control which contains the text boxes appears it does not fire the `OnPaint` event. I've no idea why this is happening.

My code is as follows

CustomTaskBox class

```
Public Class CustomTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    <Browsable(True)>
    <Category("Extended Properties")>
    <Description("Set TextBox border Color")>
    Public Sub New()

        Multiline = False
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

    End Sub


    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Dim buttonPen = New Pen(Color.Firebrick, 3)
        Dim buttonRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width - 1, Size.Height - 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(buttonPen, buttonRect)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Main Class

```
Dim _NewTextBox As New CustomTextBox
_NewTextBox.Name = textBoxName
_NewTextBox.Multiline = multiline
_NewTextBox.Text = textBoxText
_NewTextBox.Top = topForNextControl
_NewTextBox.Left = 17
_NewTextBox.Width = textBoxWidth * widthScaleFactor
_MainContent.Controls.Add(_NewTextBox)
```

Comment: The TextBox control still harks back to the 1990s.  It doesn't call a paint event.  You would have to override the WndProc to find the message.  Custom painting the TextBox control never ends well.  Just stick it inside a panel to create a border.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for your comment. I can't believe that textbox doesn't call a paint event and it is that awkward to add a border colour to a textbox. Quite shocking really

Comment: WPF lets you customize all that kind of stuff.  WinForms has legacy issues that it deals with.  See [Textbox custom onPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17414693/719186) for someone else's attempt.

Comment: To have a TextBox raise the OnPaint event, you could use the SetStyle method: `Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)`. But this is just a hack (you'll see when you try to set the Background color). It's much less complicated with a UserControl that contains a TextBox. However, take a look at [Change border color in TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466067/change-border-color-in-textbox-c-sharp/39420512#39420512).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly - you need to use`Invalidate();` to notify that control needs to be repainted.